# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'<uint8>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMuatableRawpointer?)'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to update my project to swift 3.0, and I'm having trouble in the UnsafeMutablePointer.

here is my error

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<uint8>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMuatableRawpointer?)'
```

code:

```
let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
let src_buff = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!)
let dataBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(src_buff)    //error here
```

why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting from void pointer (aka `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`) has changed in Swift 3. You have 2 options:

If you know your buffer length (safer):

```
let dataBuffer = src_buff?.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: len)
```

If you don't know it:

```
let dataBuffer = src_buff?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
```

Comment: thx!!!  it worked!